# Symfony CMS, command doctrine:generate:entities does not work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Questions?
How to generate getters and setters in Symfony CMS for documents?
Why namespace TaskBundle or Acme\TaskBundle is not recognised by the command doctrine:entities generate?

I have installed the standard-edition of CMS and try to make examples from official documentation:
http://symfony.com/doc/master/cmf/book/database_layer.html

I need to generate setters and getters for the Document Task.php

For this i decided to use command "doctrine:generate:entities". Thus created a new folder Entities and copied Task.php file from Document folder:
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition\src\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task.php
I hoped to generate setters and getters and than copy them back to the Document\Task.php

Command doctrine:generate:entities was not existing.
Thus i updated comsposer.json
C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition\composer.json

```
    "require": {
...
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.4.8",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
```

But now i am getting the error about namespace:

```
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition>php app/console generate:doctrine:entities TaskBundle:Task
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'TaskBundle'.

c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition>php app/console generate:doctrine:entity
The Entity shortcut name: Acme/TaskBundle:Task
Bundle "Acme\TaskBundle" does not exist.
The Entity shortcut name: TaskBundle:Task
Bundle "TaskBundle" does not exist.
```

C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition\src\Acme\TaskBundle\Entity\Task.php

```
   <?php

    /* If you use annotations, you'll need 
     * to prepend all annotations with @PHPCR\, 
     * which is the name of the imported namespace 
     * (e.g. @PHPCR\Document(..)), 
     * this is not shown in Doctrine's documentation. 
     * You'll also need to include the 
     * use Doctrine\ODM\PHPCR\Mapping\Annotations as PHPCR;
     *  statement to import the PHPCR annotations prefix. */


    // src/Acme/TaskBundle/Entity/Task.php
    namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

    class Task
    {
         /**
         * @PHPCR\Id()
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @PHPCR\String()
         */
        protected $description;

        /**
         * @PHPCR\Boolean()
         */
        protected $done = false;

        /**
         * @PHPCR\ParentDocument()
         */
        protected $parentDocument;
    }



Questions?
How to generate getters and setters in Symfony CMS for documents?
Why namespace TaskBundle or Acme\TaskBundle is not recognised by the command doctrine:entities generate?
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way is to write own script for setters and getters generation.

File example (com.php) is below. 
In this case one has to input field names to the custom array $avar and also write the correct path to the file where setters and getters will be generated. 
Than save the file to the directory where console is directed (for example c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\symfony\project1\com.php) and run command line:
c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\sym_prog\standard-edition>php com.php

```
<?php
//c:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0\symfony\project1\com.php

//write here own field names, for which you need setters and getters
$avar=[ "description", "done", "parentDocument" ];
$sstr="<?php ";

foreach($avar as $item){
    $uitem=ucfirst($item);
        echo($item);

    $sstr=$sstr."

    /**
     * Set $item
     *
     * @param string \$$item
     *
     * @return **ADD**
     */
    public function set$uitem(\$$item)
    {
        \$this->$item = \$$item;

        return \$this;
    }

    /**
     * Get $item
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function get$uitem()
    {
        return \$this->$item;
    }
    ";
 }   

//write here the path and filenae where setters and getters will be generated
// or you can append the file, where you need setters and getters
    $fcom=fopen("C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.4.38-0symfony\project1\a.php","w");
    fwrite($fcom,$sstr);
    fclose($fcom);

//copy setter and getters to file, where you need them.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
php app/console generate:doctrine:entities AcmeTaskBundle:Task
```

Comment: Thanks. Using your command i am still getting the error:   [RuntimeException]
  Bundle "AcmeTaskBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.

Comment: Did you add your namespace in Task entity?

Comment: I have edited the question and pasted whole Task.php file. It has namespace Acme\TaskBundle\Entity;

Comment: I mean it has namespace  Acme\TaskBundle\Entity . But i am getting the error :  [RuntimeException]
 Bundle "AcmeTaskBundle" does not contain any mapped entities.

Comment: Yes because you don't use a doctrine entity and in your case you cannot use generate:doctrine:entities. if you want to generate setter and getter you can use your IDE directly.

Comment: I created Entity folder and copied Task.php from the Document folder, also correcting namespace. From my understanding now Entity\Task.php should be treated as Entity and generate:doctrine:entities should generate setters and getters, which i later can copy and paste to the Document\Task.php

Comment: No this will not resolve your problem. However, if you want just to generate your setter and getter. You can use this solution but, you must add @ORM\Entity in your Task class.